# UnicodeDecodeError on Github code

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm studying tensorflow now

I downloaded codes of YoonKim's paper on this website

http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/

I use pycharm on windows 10 and I installed python3.5.3, Numpy and tensorflow

I just downloaded this code on the website

and I read readme.txt file .

I followed the instruction. I didn't touch any codes.

Following Readme file, I activated train.py on pycharm.

But I have error like this

[image: Error]

It seems I have to change rt-polarity.neg, rt-polarity.pos to UTF8.

But I dont know how cause I'm not good at python.

Need some help

Comment: I assume those files are encoded with UTF-8, but pycharm is configured to use `cp949` as the filesystem encoding (and your command prompt terminal is probably configured with that encoding as well). Does `import sys;print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())` print `cp949`?

Comment: It prints "mbcs" on me looks like my encoding type is very wrong..;;

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake. `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` is the encoding used for filenames. I _should_ have said: `import sys;print(sys.getdefaultencoding())`. Sorry!

Comment: yeap it prints utf-8 ....... it seems text file which the links gives has different encoding  i changed both pos and neg files to my own text files and it works... but still figuring out what the problem is

Comment: In the `data_helpers.py`, attempt to change those two `open` calls (lines 34 and 36) to include an explicit encoding: `open(positive_data_file, "r", encoding="utf-8")` and `open(negative_data_file, "r", encoding="utf-8")`